# Group ring objects in a Cartesian closed category

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, cartesian-closed-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a Cartesian closed category, with $R$ a [ring object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ring+object) in $\mathcal{C}$ and $G$ a [group object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+object) in $\mathcal{C}$.

> Is there literature on the notion of the 'group ring object' $R^G$?

The motivation here is a generalized abstract study of the various 'group rings' that appear throughout analysis/algebra, power series/Laurent/Pusiex/Levi-Civita/Hahn series fields etc.

We could ask this question more generally in any Cartesian monoidal category; any literature in this case is appreciated.

This question could probably be asked even more generally about $\infty$-something objects in an appropriate notion of $\infty$-category; any literature in this case is also appreciated.

Comment: The ordinary group ring is generally not the same as all functions $R^G$ when $G$ is infinite. A better starting point would be to view it as the free $R$-module on $G$, with the induced multiplicative structure.

Comment: @ReidBarton I’m not sure what you mean by ‘ordinary group ring’ — finite supports? I am generally more interested in the versions without implicit finiteness conditions, but if more literature exists in this case it would be appreciated.